# how can i create a google talk like system?

Tags: chat, call, audio-streaming, voice

i want to create a system that allow my site users talk talk to each other. simple like google talk.
i tried google talk but they just allow people to talk to their google firends and not to their friends on my website.
so what am i supposed to do. where should i start and what language do i need to use?
or in another way, how can i stream audio directly from the users microphone to the other user and at the same time stream the other users voice to the one in this side?
i looked in google and i couldnt found anything that can help me.

Comment: Web site chat systems are around and widely available. Search the web and you'll find one.

Answer (score 2):

This plugin for ejabberd could be what you're looking for: [a multi-user web interface to a Jabber chatroom](http://www.ejabberd.im/muckl).

Note that you'd need to set up your own Jabber server for this, but it's not extremely hard. (it's indeed "simple like google talk", except that Google Talk isn't too simple; note also that Google Talk is actually built on Jabber)